# WPF Binding does not work when binding to an object in a View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm creating a contact list in WPF using MVVM. When the user adds a contact the NewContact view will be in a window. The text boxes should be bound to an object called NewContact in the NewContactViewModel. The DataContext is set to an AppViewModel which is the central view model, but in there is a NewContact View Model called "NewContactVM" in the AppViewModel. Because I band directly to that VM I would expect it to work. Here's the NewContact.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ContactList.Windows.NewContact"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContactList"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ContactList.ViewModels"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:ContactList.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="NewContact" Height="450" Width="400">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:AppViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Border Padding="10">
            <StackPanel>

                <!-- Contact Entries-->
                <!-- Contact Name -->
                <TextBlock Text="Contact Name" Margin="5 10" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding NewContactVM.NewContact.Name,
                    FallbackValue=NULL, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          Padding="2" Margin="5 0" ></TextBox>
                <!-- Contact Number -->
                <TextBlock Text="Contact Number" Margin="5 10" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding NewContactVM.NewContact.PhoneNumber, FallbackValue=NULL, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     Padding="2" Margin="5 0"></TextBox>
                <!-- Contact Email -->
                <TextBlock Text="Contact Email" Margin="5 10" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding NewContactVM.NewContact.Email, FallbackValue=NULL, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     Padding="2" Margin="5 0"></TextBox>

                <!-- Add Contact Button -->
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button x:Name="AddContactButton"  Grid.Column="1" Content="Add Contact" 
                            Command="{Binding NewContactVM.SaveContactCommand}" Margin="10"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, whenever the NewContact is added it is always a NULL value. This is the NewContactViewModel:

```
    public class NewContactViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        private List<Contact> _contacts;

        private Contact _newContact;
        public Contact NewContact
        {
            get { return _newContact; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _newContact, value); }
        }

        public ICommand OpenNewContactWindowCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand SaveContactCommand { get; private set; }

        private IContactDataService _dataService;


        public NewContactViewModel(IContactDataService dataService)
        {
            _dataService = dataService;
            _contacts = dataService.GetContacts().ToList();
            OpenNewContactWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(showNewContact);
            SaveContactCommand = new RelayCommand(Save);
        }

        private void showNewContact()
        {
            NewContact newContact = new NewContact();
            newContact.Show();
        }

        private void Save()
        {
            Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(_contacts);
            _dataService.Save(_contacts);
            Contacts.Add(NewContact);
            _contacts.Add(NewContact);

        }
    }
```

Because the value's always null the binding must not happen but I can't figure out why, I'm new to the MVVM architecture. (For reference the Contact object is just a custom object with public strings for Names with getters and setters).

Comment: Where and how do you assign the new Contact object to the NewContact property?

Comment: Isn't that what binding would do, do you have to assign a Contact object to the NewContact?

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to ask me here. If you think the binding would assign the Contact object to the NewContact property, where do you think would the binding get the Contact object from?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. By the NewContact property are you referring to the NewContact in the .xaml?

Comment: I am referring to the NewContact property in your NewContactViewModel class. In the code in your question there is no NewContact property anywhere else...

Comment: The NewContact is already a Contact. By assign the new Contact object do you mean give it a "non-null" value?

Comment: Well, object instances cannot be represented or referred to by the value `null`, or? ;-)

Comment: Where would it make sense to assign NewContact as a Contact?

Comment: That's up to you to decide, it depends what the things are you would want your code do with a Contact object in the NewContact property, and how your particular interaction logic should work with regard to the information and or state maintained by this Contact object. Maybe create a Contact object and assign it to the NewContact property as part of the initialization of the NewContactViewModel instance. Perhaps that would work, perhaps that would be a bad idea with regard to your application scenario (which i don't know about). There is only one person who can really answer this question: You

Comment: In `NewContactViewModel ` the property `NewContact`, which is the target of your bindings, is never initialized and therefore always NULL.

Comment: I guess to fix this, the first line in `showNewContact()` must change from `NewContact newContact = new NewContact();` to `this.NewContact = new NewContact();` Then in the second line call `this.NewContact.Show();`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly your code works like this:

1. Your main ViewModel is Called AppViewModel
2. In your AppViewModel You have a NewContactVM which is a NewContactViewModel class
3. In your NewContactVM you have a showNewContact method where you create a new NewContact window.
4. The new instance of NewContact window creates a new (possibly uninitialized) AppViewModel. Now you have a totally new second AppViewModel, because of this code.

   ```
   <Window.DataContext>
       <local:AppViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
   ```

Fix:

Since all your bindings are referencing AppViewModel.NewContactVM you should simply change the datacontext of the new window.

1. First remove this code from your XAML

   ```
   <Window.DataContext>
       <local:AppViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
   ```
2. Then change your showNewContact method to set the DataContext properly.

   ```
   private void showNewContact()
   {
       NewContact newContact = new NewContact();
       newContact.DataContext = this;
       newContact.Show();
   }
   ```

Update:

If your NewContact property is null it's because it isn't initialized anywhere.

Try changing this:

```
private Contact _newContact;
public Contact NewContact
{
    get { return _newContact; }
    set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _newContact, value); }
}
```

to this

```
private Contact _newContact = new Contact();
public Contact NewContact
{
    get { return _newContact; }
    set { _newContact = value; }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, the 2 AppViewModels was my mistake. Although, even after these changes and adjusting the xaml for the new Data Context, the newContacts is still null

Comment: I don't see a newContacts property anywhere in the code you posted. If you meant NewContact property, then I also don't see anywhere a value is assigned. Properties are null by default unless you assign a new object to them.